# NoMethodError with nil object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi sorry if this is a silly question, realy I'm new in the ROR world and I'm trying to learn.

I'm reading the Agile Web Develpment with Rails eBook and following the book program I got stock with this error:

> NoMethodError in Line itemsController#create
>
> You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
>   You might have expected an instance of Array.
>   The error occurred while evaluating nil.

This is the cart Model

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy

  def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = line_items.where(:product_id => product_id).first
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity += 1
    else
      current_item = LineItem.new(:product_id => product_id)
      line_items << current_item
    end
    current_item
  end
end
```

And this is the Line Item controller which method is being called

```
  def create
    @cart = current_cart
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])    
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@line_item.cart, :notice => 'Line item was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item.cart, :status => :created, :location => @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Rails version 3.0.5
Ruby version 1.8.7

Any suggestion ? can you see what is wrong ? 
Thanks

Comment: Please, post the line number.

Comment: Post the full error with stack trace, you're omitting critical information.

Comment: You are not going to any useful help until you post the line number of the error.

Answer (score 2):

When it reports a NoMethodError on a nil object, it means that an object you are calling a method on does not exist. Here, it could be that either `@cart` or `@line_item` have no data, depending on which line number the error is occurring on. So it may be that

```
@cart = current_cart
```

...or...

```
@line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)
```

are not returning a valid object. Look into those methods.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that an object that you are calling a method on is nil.  The error message should have a line number on it that should point at the offending line of code causing the problem.

Just a guess, but could current_cart return nil?  That would be my initial hunch, but if you could highlight what line was the cause of the error, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`NoMethodError` means that you're calling a method which is not defined for an instance of the class which you are calling a method of, in this case the class of the object you're trying to call a method for is `NilClass`. If you aren't sure what object is nil, you can always ask irb with `obj.class`, though, as the other answerer said, it should tell you which line contains the error (if not the exact syntax).